# Get a mesh_3 'off' from Projection_traits_xy_3 constrained delaunay

Tags: c++, cgal

I've computed a 2D constrained delaunay triangulation from 2.5D data using the `projection_traits_xy_3` [1]. Now I would like to get a mesh that I can visualize.

I've managed to do that with 3d delaunay following the manual[2], how could I achieve it with a 2.5D CDT ?

```
[...]
typedef CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<K>  Gt;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds> CDT;
[...]
CDT cdt;
cdt.insert(points.begin(),points.end());
[...]
¿?
[...]
std::ofstream out(outdir + "out.off");
Polyhedron output_mesh;
CGAL::output_surface_facets_to_polyhedron(¿?, output_mesh);
out << output_mesh;
```

[1] http://pastebin.com/HzAwrnW5

[2] http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Point_set_processing_3/index.html#chappoint_set_processing_3
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_reconstruction_points_3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Andreas suggestion:

Here comes the code for writing it into an off file

```
std::ofstream outstream("output.off");
outstream << "OFF\n"  << cdt.number_of_vertices()
      << " "  << cdt.number_of_faces() << " 0" << std::endl;

std::map<CDT::Vertex_handle,int> indices;
int counter = 0;

for(CDT::Finite_vertices_iterator it = cdt.finite_vertices_begin(); it != cdt.finite_vertices_end(); ++it)
{
  outstream << it->point() << std::endl;
  indices.insert(std::pair<CDT::Vertex_handle,int>(it, counter++));
}

for(CDT::Finite_faces_iterator it = cdt.finite_faces_begin(); it != cdt.finite_faces_end(); ++it)
{
  outstream << "3 " << indices[it->vertex(0)] 
            << " "  << indices[it->vertex(1)]
            << " "  << indices[it->vertex(2)] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here comes pseudocode forwriting it into an off file

```
cout << "OFF\n"  << cdt.number_of_vertices() 
      << " "  << cdt.number_of_faces() << " 0" << std::endl;

std::map<vertex_handle,int> indices;
int counter = 0;

for all finite vertices v  {   
  cout << v->point() <<std::endl;
  indices.insert(v, counter++); 
}

for all finite faces f {  
  cout << "3 " << indices[f->vertex(0)]    
       << " "  << indices[f->vertex(1)] 
       << " "  << indices[f->vertex(2)] << std::endl;  
}
```

Comment: I've done it, if you'd prefer me writing another answer revert the changes and I'll commit a proper answer.

Comment: grmbl, my edit got rejected :/ This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner